# Why do I need to enable CORS on the tomcat application

Tags: java, angularjs, tomcat, cors

I have an application running on a tomcat 8 server, on a domain
and an Angular web app. The web app uses the tomcat application, but without enabling filtering in the web.xml the webapp will mention problems.

Here is how I make the js requests to the tomcat application

```
function getResources($http, url){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}
        }).then(function (result) {
            return result.data;
      });
};
```

I've also tried with : `dataType: 'jsonp'`

The error looks like:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/APP/requestStuff.No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Which is strange to me, because if the origin is the same as where I am connected it shouldn't be cross origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cross origin request policy applies any time the scheme (e.g. http vs https), domain, or ports vary. So in your case because the ports differ you will need CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it a relative url instead of a canonical one.

The sites also need to share the same port.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules

Also, be sure you are getting the right URL.  If you were literally quoting the error as "Origin 'the_IP_of_web_app'", for example, it failed because that wasn't an IP Address.

Comment: I don't want to disclose the exact IP, but running on localhost runs into the same issue I changed my question.

Comment: In your new question you are using different ports.  That will fail.

Comment: I'm running a python simpleHTTPserver at port 8000, the web page definitely comes up. Just the requests cause the error.

Comment: But you're trying to connect to it from a browser showing an app hosted on port 8080?  If so, that is the problem, and CORS needs to be set up.  I would also test it in multiple browsers, because they tend to vary in how strict they are.